# Aggregate dataframe columns by hourly index

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas dataframe that is taking in / out interface traffic every 10 minutes. I want to aggregate the two time series into hourly buckets for analysis. What seems to be simple has actually ended up being quite challenging for me to figure out! Just need to bucket into hourly bins

```
times = list()
ins = list()
outs = list()

for row in results['results']:
    times.append(row['DateTime'])
    ins.append(row['Intraffic'])
    outs.append(row['Outtraffic'])



df = pd.DataFrame()
df['datetime'] = times
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.index = df['datetime'] 
df['ins'] = ins
df['outs'] = outs
```

I have tried using

```
df.resample('H').mean()
```

I have tried pandas

```
groupby
```

but was having trouble with the two columns and getting the means over the hourly bucket

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['datetime'] = times
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime',inplace=True) # This won't try to remap your rows
new_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).mean()
```

That last line groups your data by timestamp into hourly chunks, based on the index, and then spits out a new DataFrame with the mean of each column.